# TimeDiff function in JDBC sql

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, time, difference

I'm trying to create an sql statement in java that uses the timediff function to compare two sql date objects from a table. This is what my statement looks like:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEID, COUNT(ORDER_TYPE) AS BREAKFASTCOUNT, MIN(TIMEDIFF(ORDER_ACCEPTED_TIME,ORDER_COMPLETION_TIME)) AS MINPREP, MAX(TIMEDIFF(ORDER_ACCEPTED_TIME, ORDER_COMPLETION_TIME)) AS MAXPREP FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDERDATE BETWEEN '4/01/2015' AND '4/30/2015' AND ORDER_TYPE ='Breakfast' GROUP BY EMPLOYEEID
```

However, when I run this statement I get the error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'TIMEDIFF' is not recognized as a function or procedure.
```

Is there any reason why this error is occurring?

Comment: never heard of a TIMEDIFF function in sql server and so has google.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this is the query your are looking for. This shows time difference in minutes.

```
SELECT 
    EMPLOYEEID, 
    COUNT(ORDER_TYPE) AS BREAKFASTCOUNT,
    MIN(dateDIFF(MINUTE,ORDER_ACCEPTED_TIME,ORDER_COMPLETION_TIME)) AS MINPREP, 
    MAX(dateDIFF(MINUTE,ORDER_ACCEPTED_TIME, ORDER_COMPLETION_TIME)) AS MAXPREP 
FROM ORDERS 
WHERE ORDERDATE BETWEEN '4/01/2015' AND '4/30/2015' 
AND ORDER_TYPE ='Breakfast' 
GROUP BY EMPLOYEEID
```